# ValueError: torch.cuda.is_available() should be True but is False

Tags: pytorch

I’m trying to train a custom model using kohya. I have been running into the same error for over 1 week now. I’ve attached photos of my error message as well as some information about my computer and the applications on it. I’m thinking I have an issue with my setup, but I’m not sure what it is or how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated!!!

Error Message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\sdxl_train_network.py", line 189, in <module>
    trainer.train(args)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\train_network.py", line 242, in train
    vae.set_use_memory_efficient_attention_xformers(args.xformers)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\modeling_utils.py", line 263, in set_use_memory_efficient_attention_xformers
    fn_recursive_set_mem_eff(module)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\modeling_utils.py", line 259, in fn_recursive_set_mem_eff
    fn_recursive_set_mem_eff(child)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\modeling_utils.py", line 259, in fn_recursive_set_mem_eff
    fn_recursive_set_mem_eff(child)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\modeling_utils.py", line 259, in fn_recursive_set_mem_eff
    fn_recursive_set_mem_eff(child)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\modeling_utils.py", line 256, in fn_recursive_set_mem_eff
    module.set_use_memory_efficient_attention_xformers(valid, attention_op)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\diffusers\models\attention_processor.py", line 255, in set_use_memory_efficient_attention_xformers
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: torch.cuda.is_available() should be True but is False. xformers' memory efficient attention is only available for GPU
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Allison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\Allison\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\Scripts\accelerate.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\accelerate\commands\accelerate_cli.py", line 47, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\accelerate\commands\launch.py", line 986, in launch_command
    simple_launcher(args)
  File "D:\Kohya\kohya_ss\venv\lib\site-packages\accelerate\commands\launch.py", line 628, in simple_launcher
    raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(returncode=process.returncode, cmd=cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['D:\\Kohya\\kohya_ss\\venv\\Scripts\\python.exe', './sdxl_train_network.py', '--enable_bucket', '--min_bucket_reso=256', '--max_bucket_reso=2048', '--pretrained_model_name_or_path=D:/Kohya/kohya_ss/sdXL_v10VAEFix.safetensors', '--train_data_dir=C:/Users/Allison/Downloads/jrm/jrm_lora\\img', '--resolution=1024, 1024', '--output_dir=C:/Users/Allison/Downloads/jrm/jrm_lora\\model', '--logging_dir=C:/Users/Allison/Downloads/jrm/jrm_lora\\log', '--network_alpha=64', '--training_comment=jrm', '--save_model_as=safetensors', '--network_module=networks.lora', '--text_encoder_lr=4e-07', '--unet_lr=0.0001', '--network_dim=128', '--output_name=jrm_lora', '--lr_scheduler_num_cycles=1', '--no_half_vae', '--learning_rate=4e-07', '--lr_scheduler=constant_with_warmup', '--lr_warmup_steps=200', '--train_batch_size=1', '--max_train_steps=2001', '--save_every_n_epochs=1', '--mixed_precision=fp16', '--save_precision=fp16', '--cache_latents', '--optimizer_type=Adafactor', '--max_grad_norm=1', '--max_data_loader_n_workers=0', '--bucket_reso_steps=64', '--mem_eff_attn', '--gradient_checkpointing', '--xformers', '--bucket_no_upscale', '--noise_offset=0.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

nvcc --version:

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2023 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov_22_10:30:42_Pacific_Standard_Time_2023
Cuda compilation tools, release 12.3, V12.3.107
Build cuda_12.3.r12.3/compiler.33567101_0
```

python -m torch.utils.collect_env:

```
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 2.1.2+cu118
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: 11.8
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 10 Home
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.10.6 (tags/v3.10.6:9c7b4bd, Aug  1 2022, 21:53:49) [MSC v.1932 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
Is CUDA available: True
CUDA runtime version: 12.3.107
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: LAZY
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070
Nvidia driver version: 546.12
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Architecture=9
CurrentClockSpeed=3200
DeviceID=CPU0
Family=107
L2CacheSize=4096
L2CacheSpeed=
Manufacturer=AuthenticAMD
MaxClockSpeed=3200
Name=AMD Ryzen 7 2700 Eight-Core Processor
ProcessorType=3
Revision=2050

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] numpy==1.24.1
[pip3] torch==2.1.2+cu118
[pip3] torchaudio==2.1.2+cu118
[pip3] torchvision==0.16.2+cu118
[conda] Could not collect
```

nvidia-smi:

[Image of NVIDIA-SMI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAVx1.png)

ValueError: torch.cuda.is_available() should be True but is False. I've been trying to figure out how to fix this error message. I've looked at multiple forums and tried to implement their solutions on github, pytorch, and stackoverflow with no success.

Comment: What is the result of `>>> torch.cuda.is_available()` just plain and simple torch without third party networks?